# Dask datetime optimization

Tags: python, datetime, dask

I would like to know how to optimize this transformation, I need calculate the day of week for 125 millions of rows, I have a computer with 4 GB of RAM, I just trying with this:

```
df_train['date'].dt.dayofweek.compute()
```

And my PC with Ubuntu 16.04 and Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 @ 2.5 GHz is just freezing and i need to reboot it

Is there any idea to optimize this?

Comment: If your computer is freezing due to memory issues, have you considered simply outputting each day of week to a file line by line (e.g. csv or hdf5)? This should have minimal memory overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Your data set is about 1 GB in size (125M rows, 8 bytes each).  And stupidly, `dayofweek` returns a int64 (8 bytes).  So whilst performing this calculation, at least 2 GB of memory will be used (plus some smaller overhead).

It's not clear how you will ever be able to do meaningful work *in memory* with this much data on such a small computer.  I suggest splitting the data into a few chunks (e.g. 10), saving those chunks to disk, then loading and operating on one at a time.  100 MB of input data at a time is more than sufficient to keep your processor cores (and memory) busy.

Another idea: if you have a lot of duplicate dates (which surely you must), create a Series indexed by unique dates with the values being `dayofweek.astype('i1')`.  This will be a much more compact way to represent the same information (whether it is practical depends on details of your further processing, which we don't know).